# JSON nested struct to itself in Go Language

Tags: json, go, struct, nested

I have below JSON

```
[{
  "id": 8,
  "title": "Indonesia",
  "type": "country",
  "attributes": {
    "regionCode": "ID",
    "information": {
      "title": "Welcome to Indonesia",
      "content": "We only serve selected areas in Indonesia.",
      "image": "indo.png"
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "title": "Jakarta",
      "type": "city",
      "attributes": {
        "regionCode": "ID-JKT",
        "information": {
          "title": "Welcome to Capital City of Indonesia",
          "content": "We only serve selected areas in Jabotabek",
          "image": "jakarta.png"
        }
      }       
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "title": "Bali",
      "type": "city",
      "attributes": {
        "regionCode": "ID-BAL",
        "information": {
          "title": "Welcome to the beach city Bali",
          "content": "We only serve selected areas in Bali.",
          "image": "bali.png"
        }   
      }       
    }
  ]
}]
```

Technically this is a nested structure to itself as the children node, and the children might have children as well. But i just couldnt get it right when im using unmarshal to decode this.

The working one is like below `i have no problem defining the attribute as a separate struct so assuming i have locationAttribute struct`

```
type locationNode []struct {
    ID         string             `json:"id"`
    Title      string             `json:"title"`
    Type       string             `json:"type"`
    Attributes locationAttribute `json:"attributes"`
    Children   []struct {
        ID         string             `json:"id"`
        Title      string             `json:"title"`
        Type       string             `json:"type"`
        Attributes locationAttribute `json:"attributes"`
        Children   []interface{}      `json:"children"`
    } `json:"children"`
}
```

However im expecting to be something like below

```
type locationNode []struct {
    ID         string             `json:"id"`
    Title      string             `json:"title"`
    Type       string             `json:"type"`
    Attributes locationAttribute `json:"attributes"`
    Children   []locationNode `json:"children"`
}
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What is the question? You can use `Children []locationNode` and it will work.

Comment: umm but i got an error
{"error":"json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []address.locationNode"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to resolve this - it's actually a silly careless mistake, since my struct is already an array I should NOT define the children as an array.

So below definition works

```
type locationNode []struct {
  ID         string             `json:"id"`
  Title      string             `json:"title"`
  Type       string             `json:"type"`
  Attributes locationAttribute  `json:"attributes"`
  Children   locationNode     `json:"children"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ your JSON converts to

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
    Attributes struct {
        RegionCode string `json:"regionCode"`
        Information struct {
            Title string `json:"title"`
            Content string `json:"content"`
            Image string `json:"image"`
        } `json:"information"`
    } `json:"attributes"`
    Children []struct {
        ID int `json:"id"`
        Title string `json:"title"`
        Type string `json:"type"`
        Attributes struct {
            RegionCode string `json:"regionCode"`
            Information struct {
                Title string `json:"title"`
                Content string `json:"content"`
                Image string `json:"image"`
            } `json:"information"`
        } `json:"attributes"`
    } `json:"children"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this is not ideal bcoz technically the children could have children and so on.
  "children": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Jakarta",
        "type": "city",
        "attributes": {},
        "children": [{},{},{}]
    },...

Comment: It's important to know that the tool exists plus it should give you a head start in customizing it to your need.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that in the JSON text the `"id"` field is a number and not `string`, it works for me.

Omitting the `"attributes"` to make the example shorter:

```
type locationNode struct {
    ID       int            `json:"id"`
    Title    string         `json:"title"`
    Type     string         `json:"type"`
    Children []locationNode `json:"children"`
}

func main() {
    ln := locationNode{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &ln)

    fmt.Printf("%+v %v\n", ln, err)
}

const src = `{
  "id": 8,
  "title": "Indonesia",
  "type": "country",
  "attributes": {
    "regionCode": "ID",
    "information": {
      "title": "Welcome to Indonesia",
      "content": "We only serve selected areas in Indonesia.",
      "image": "indo.png"
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "title": "Jakarta",
      "type": "city",
      "attributes": {
        "regionCode": "ID-JKT",
        "information": {
          "title": "Welcome to Capital City of Indonesia",
          "content": "We only serve selected areas in Jabotabek",
          "image": "jakarta.png"
        }
      }       
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "title": "Bali",
      "type": "city",
      "attributes": {
        "regionCode": "ID-BAL",
        "information": {
          "title": "Welcome to the beach city Bali",
          "content": "We only serve selected areas in Bali.",
          "image": "bali.png"
        }   
      }       
    }
  ]
}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1_7ndrg9Ni)):

```
{ID:8 Title:Indonesia Type:country Children:[{ID:9 Title:Jakarta Type:city Children:[]} {ID:10 Title:Bali Type:city Children:[]}]} <nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks like defining `Children` in the way you expect works fine. The following both marshals and unmarshals fine.

```
type Bob struct {
    ID         string            `json:"id"`
    Title      string            `json:"title"`
    Type       string            `json:"type"`
    Attributes int               `json:"attributes"`
    Children   []Bob             `json:"children"`
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/KN5R3_RqoX)